# Haskell Filtering but keeping the filtered

Tags: haskell

In my understanding, the Haskell `filter` function `filter a bs` would filter all `a`'s from a list `bs`.

Is there a simple method or variation of `filter` that would do the opposite, only keeping the `a`'s from the list `bs`, basically creating a list of `a`'s.

Comment: As an aside... I _always_ seem to get `filter` the wrong way around. `filter odd` sounds like it's going to _filter out_ all the odd values. Actually it filters out the _even_ values. Wuh?? I think Smalltalk had this right; it had two functions named `select` and `reject`. Makes it _much_ clearer what it does! (Of course, nobody is going to rename the Prelude functions _now_...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, that's imprecise wording anyway. The signature is

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

so `filter a bs` is described as *filter all elements from `bs` that **fulfill** `a`*.

So to "do the opposite", you just need to invert the predicate. For instance,

> Prelude> filter (== 'a') "Is there a simple method or variation of filter that"
>   "aaaa"
>   Prelude> filter (/= 'a') "Is there a simple method or variation of filter that"
>   "Is there  simple method or vrition of filter tht"

In general:

```
filterNot :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filterNot pred = filter $ not . pred
```

> Prelude> filterNot (== 'a') "Is there a simple method or variation of filter that"
>   "Is there  simple method or vrition of filter tht"

Answer (score 4):

```
remove f = filter (not . f)

> remove odd [1..10]
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` function takes a predicate function of the type `a -> Bool` and a list of type `[a]`, and it applies the predicate to each element of the list to determine if it should be kept.  As an example, you could do `filter (\x -> x < 2 || x > 10) someNumbers`, which would return a list of all the values from `someNumbers` that are either less than 2 or greater than 10.

If you wanted all of a particular element from a list, you could do

```
only :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
only x xs = filter (== x) xs
```

Since the predicate is then checking if each element is equal to a particular one.

Answer (score 1):

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

> filter (<5) [1 .. 10]
[1,2,3,4]
```

It filter some elements which saisfy some condition

The opposite function is the same function with negative boolean condition

```
filterNot f = filter (not . f)

> filterNot (<5) [1 .. 10]
[5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, what lead me to this page, a way to keep both a's and b's, but separated:

```
> foldl (\(evens,odds) e -> if e `mod` 2 == 0 then (e:evens, odds) else (evens, e:odds)) ([],[]) (reverse [1..10])
```

([2,4,6,8,10],[1,3,5,7,9])

Comment: Or just use the `partition` function from Data.List: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition

Comment: ... perfect. I was looking for that when I found this page xDD.
Glad to have that here as Google may direct others. Thanks Ben.